# Prevent Anonymous Access to Folder and sub Folders

Tags: iis-7, web-config, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I'm using VS 2010 with .NET 4.0 and SQL 2008 Membership/Role providers. My goal is to only allow access to a folder named "members" (and it's subdirectories) for those users that have logged in and are in the role of "member". There are not any asp pages in the "members" folder, just files such as jpegs. On my development machine, I have configured my root web.config file as follows:

```
          <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
<location path="members">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="member"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This all works fine on my development machine. However, when I publish to my production server it does not work ... all users can access the folder "members" not just the users that have logged in as a "member" role.

My production server is running IIS 7. I think the problem lies there. I added Authorization Rules in the IIS Manager for "member" to allow access and deny anonymous users. This made no difference.

Any ideas?
Thanks ... Bob
PS: I propose calling them mouse users, I hate spelling anonymous.

Comment: Found the answer in a previous post listed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218254/has-there-been-a-change-to-the-way-asp-net-authorization-authentication-deals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, roles were incorrect in IIS.